How to replace repetitive string value with values in a list?
I'm trying to create simple Python program for below example.
Sentence = "Person A has ? baloon, Person B has ? baloon Person C has ? baloon"

There can be n number of balloons in this sentence.
Color = ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]

There can be n number of colors.
FinalSentence = "Person A has Black baloon, Person B has Blue baloon Person C has Red baloon"

Trying to replace ? in Sentence with the colors in list Color sequentially.
I've applied FinalSentence = Sentence.replace("?", Color[0]) with loop. Not sure if this is correct way of thinking.

You could use string formatting with the built-in str.format() method:
sentence = "Person A has ? baloon, Person B has ? baloon Person C has ? baloon"
color = ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]

final = sentence.replace("?", "{}").format(*color)
print(final)
# >>> Person A has Black baloon, Person B has Blue baloon Person C has Red baloon


In the first step, we replace the given placeholder ? with a placeholder that the format() method understands, namely {}, using the str.replace() method. As a consequence, the sentence now looks as follows:
"Person A has {} baloon, Person B has {} baloon Person C has {} baloon"


In the second step, we replace the placeholders with the actual contents from the color list using the format() method. We have to "unpack" the list here, which we do with the preceding *. So, what we actually write here, is the following:
("Person A has {} baloon, Person B has {} baloon "
 "Person C has {} baloon").format("Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green")



Update: As @SIGHUP pointed out, there is one more color in the given color list (4) than there are placeholders to be replaced (3). Yet still, the approach using format() works. To find out why this mismatch does not cause an error, we can look at the corresponding source code:
It seems that the string formatter simply iterates over the placeholders (line 203), determines the argument index for the empty ones (which is the type of placeholder that we are using; line 216 and 221), and then gets the argument at the determined index from the list of arguments (line 234). Because there is no check for superfluous arguments, this implies that an argument list that is too long (as is the case here) will not cause any problems. However, whether this should be considered expected behavior or an implementation detail of an edge case is not immediately clear to me – the documentation of str.format() does not handle this case.
If we wanted to make absolutely sure that the list of arguments is no longer than the list of placeholders, we could cut it off at the count of placeholders, e.g. like so:
final = sentence.replace("?", "{}").format(*color[:sentence.count("?")])

However, as we saw, this is not necessary; at least not with the "standard" Python implementation (i.e. CPython). Also, this still doesn't handle the case of having too few arguments, but then again, this is a different problem.

It's interesting to note that the number of parameters passed to format() must be at least as many replacement fields as are in the string to which it's applied. Too few and you'll get an IndexError. Too many and the "extra" values are simply ignored. Thus, this is a perfectly reasonable solution

Sentence = "Person A has ? baloon, Person B has ? baloon Person C has ? baloon"

Color = ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]

replaced_text = Sentence

for color_ in Color:
    replaced_text = replaced_text.replace("?", color_, 1)

print(replaced_text)

Note that it assumes that the order in Color in the order that you want in your sentence.
This will iteratively replace "?" by the values within Color

Here's the stepwise approach to address your issue:
Given sentence with placeholders:
sentence = "Person A has ? balloon, Person B has ? balloon, Person C has ? balloon"
List of colors to replace the placeholders:
colors = ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]

Initialize a variable to keep track of which color to use:
color_index = 0

Iterate over the sentence and replace each '?' with the corresponding color:
while "?" in sentence:
    if color_index < len(colors):
        sentence = sentence.replace("?", colors[color_index], 1)  # Replace only the first occurrence
        color_index += 1  # Move to the next color in the list
    else:
        # If there are not enough colors to replace all '?', break to avoid infinite loop
        break

print(sentence)  # Output the final sentence

